# Does anyone use dm-cache?

Tags: performance, storage-area-network, cache, network-attached-storage

Has, or does, anyone use dm-cache - specifically for caching SAN based storage locally?

I'm looking for a way to speed up SAN based storage on a CentOS 5.6 + XEN Hypervisor which uses iSCSI mounted SAN storage. dm-cache seems like it do the trick, but I've never heard of it before until someone mentioned it in another mailing list. A quick search on google didn't really give me much in terms of actual user experience.

Does anyone use it? 
Any feedback? Pitfalls? Success stories?

I'm referring to this: https://github.com/mingzhao/dm-cache/blob/5670b91bc7c412885339f11fcf794a70c26da879/README

Answer (score 1):

After skimming the IBM Research Report about it I'm not convinced of its value. If a SAN is constructed properly the throughput and number of IOPS provided will dwarf a single (or a few) local disks.

I wish the authors would have run tests that were even close to real-life. Doesn't IBM have hardware? Instead they use an ISCSI SAN backed by a *single spindle* and we get his claim:

> It is understood that some of the
>   scalability issues ex- hibited by this
>   iSCSI-based storage system can be at-
>   tributed to the fact that a single
>   disk is used to serve the concurrent
>   client accesses. However, as
>   demonstrated by the above experiments,
>   the performance bottlenecks ap- pear
>   even for a small number of clients.
>   Therefore, it is reasonable to believe
>   that the same issues will still per-
>   sist for a better-equipped and more
>   load-balanced stor- age system, when
>   the number of clients is relatively
>   lager than the current setup.